# Groovy Closure generic return/parameters?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a method that should take a Closure with first two parameters Car and Tyre and should return a type of Vehicle.

Is there a way to declare the type of parameters in Groovy Closures?

I am thinking

```
method(Closure<Vehicle, Car, Tyre> closure);
```

but what is the correct way?

Answer (score 8):

You can only define the return type of a Closure, ie: `Closure<Vehicle>`

As of Groovy 2.3, you can use `@ClosureParam` to tweak the type system (see *"Tweaking the type system"* [here](http://melix.github.io/blog/2014/01/closure_param_inference.html)), but Groovy 2.3 is not currently in Grails I believe...

Answer (score 0):

The generic parameter on Closure is used for the return type. `Closure<String>` shall return a string.

The parameters may be declared using the `@ClosureParams` annotation

http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.0-beta-1/html/gapi/groovy/transform/stc/ClosureParams.html

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately i am on Grails 2.3.7 and below Groovy 2.3.0 :( ... also overly complex! But the return type is welcomed!